# What parametrization should I use to evaluate $\int_{\phi}x^{4/3} + y^{4/3}$, where $\phi$ is curve given by $(x^2+y^2)^2 = 9(x^2-y^2)$?

Tags: integration, curves, plane-curves

I´ve recently tried calculating this:

$$\int_{\phi}x^{4/3} + y^{4/3}$$ where $\phi$ is curve given by $(x^2+y^2)^2 = 9(x^2-y^2)$.

And I couldn´t think of any parametrization or substitution that would give me a reasonable outcome. Any suggestions?

Comment: figure 8 through the origin.   For $x >0,$  use polar coordinates.

Comment: Clarification, is this supposed to be a line integral on that curve, or a double integral bounded by that curve? I assumed the former but didn't want to keep running in circles if that wasn't the case.

Comment: Is the measure $dx$ ?

Comment: It´s line integral on that curve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equation you are considering is the lemniscate of Bernoulli, and you can parametrise it as follows:
\begin{align}
 x(t) &= 3 \frac{\cos(t)}{1+\sin^2(t)} \\
 y(t) &= 3 \frac{\sin(t) \cdot \cos(t)}{1+\sin^2(t)}
\end{align} for $t \in [0,2\pi]$.

As a further suggestion, note that to compute the line integral, you can use periodicity of the integrand to restrict the domain over which you need to integrate.

Comment: This is a good and whole parametrization (unlike many others which would be piecewise), but as an integrand it is quite horrible and not useful for the integration required. Welcome to MSE btw!

Comment: Yes, the integrand becomes indeed quite horrible. :) Perhaps the comment on symmetry might eventually be useful. And thank you!

Comment: Most of the newcomers on MSE start by asking questions. You are the first one I've seen who has started by answering questions. Have a good and long journey on this site.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and obviously I tried ploting this a noticed that it is symetrical along x and y axes. I also knew there would be some sort of sin, cos parametrization but never figured it out. Thanks a lot! Also wouldn´t it help if I used substitution of tan(Pi/2)?